# Laravel Vuejs deploy application in hosted server

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-5, vue.js

Please, I try to host my Laravel-Vuejs application in my hosted server, but it doesn't work.

I get this msg in my web inspector

```
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://sample.com/myproject/js/bootstrap.js.map
app.js:107387 app vue
app.js:18929 You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
```

And I get always blank page (components not loaded), how can I fix this, please. thanks

**Package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.17"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
        "cross-spawn": "^6.0.5",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
        "vee-validate": "^2.0.9",
        "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
        "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.5",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-scrollspy": "^0.1.3",
        "vue-spinner": "^1.0.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
        "vue2-scrollspy": "^2.3.1",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.5.2",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
    }
}
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Seems like `Vue` working correctly. It is just minor warnings. Please, provide more information

Comment: Specific how you deployed the frontend on your sever. Did you upload the sources and then build it - did you build it and then uploaded?

Comment: @FrankProvost when i try to build i get this msg: `npm ERR! missing script: build
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-08-09T12_18_24_836Z-debug.log `

Comment: @GONG I dont know what kind of information I can provide :/

Comment: @MalekBenelouafi provide your package.json `scripts` section. Seems like error is here

Comment: @GONG I edit the question

Comment: @MalekBenelouafi it seems like you trying to run `npm run build`, when you need `npm run prod` or `npm run dev`

Answer (score 1):

you need to turn Vue to production mode,

you can do so by adding this line to your app.js

```
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem, and I share with you the solution:

So this kind of problem depends on the base URL of your app router, for my situation `base: __dirname` is the problem, so I changed this to `base: '/project_name/public/`, and everything works fine.

Thank you all for you help.

Answer (score -2):

Laravel has become the most popular choice for developing PHP projects. One important reason for this popularity is the built in support for Vue.js, a very fast growing JavaScript library for developing impressive front-ends.

This combination results is fast, secure and very impressive applications that need minimum time to go from ideation to final code review. The support for Vue.js means that Laravel developers could use Vue components easily within their apps without wasting time in writing integrations for the components.

[Host you Laravel Vuejs spa](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-vue-single-page-app/)

Comment: I know all this information, I ask how I deploy the app in a hosting server